# $\forall x\exists y(P(x)\longrightarrow Q(y))\longrightarrow\exists y\forall x(P(x)\longrightarrow Q(y))$ universally valid?

Tags: logic

I tried to come up with an interpretation that makes it false, but I cant, and I cant come up with a proof by contradiction either.

If someone could point me towards the general direction, that would be great.

Comment: No, the first means for any $x$ you can find some $y$. The second means you can find a $y$ that is set for all $x$.

Comment: So its not universally valid? Could I get some tips on how to prove this formally?

Comment: So an illustration would be the difference between continuity and uniform continuity (for a fixed $\epsilon \gt 0$).

Comment: This particular formula is valid. Note that both formulae are equivalent to $\exists xP(x)\to\exists yQ(y)$.

Comment: If $\exists x(P(x))$ then for such an $x$, there must be a $y$ so that $Q(y)$ is true, and hence $P(x')$ implies $Q(y)$ for all $x'.$ Now check the case $\lnot\exists x(P(x))=\forall x(\lnot P(x)).$ In that case we can take any $y$ to get because $\text{false }\implies\text{ anything}.$

Comment: @RobertShore That would be correct if $x$ and $y$ are the same,but $x,y$ are unrelated.

Comment: @B.Swan Although that's a good instinct in general, in this specific case they happen to be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't permute $\forall$s and $\exists$s. However, this is a special case, and the implication you've described **does hold** for this very specific instance - roughly, because the two quantifiers don't really interact very much. Let's see why.

The key is to realize that $$P(x)\rightarrow Q(y)$$ is only saying "either $Q(y)$ holds or $P(x)$ fails." For example, if there is a single $a$ such that $Q(a)$ holds, then $\exists y\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(y))$ is true (set $y=a$). More generally, this should suggest that the two statements in question (especially the second) are actually a lot simpler (and weaker) than they first appear.

At this point you should try to simplify each statement: under what conditions on $P$ and $Q$ is each statement true? You can then just compare these simpler expressions.

*A good starting point: we've argued above that $\exists y\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(y))$ is true if $\exists y(Q(y))$ is true; what is the **other** way for $\exists y\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(y))$ to hold (that is, what needs to happen in order for $\exists y\forall x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(y))$ to be true if there is no $y$ such that $Q(y)$)?*

Comment: So it is universally valid? AKA it is true under all interpretations?

Comment: Yes, @TimWeah. This is one of those cases where we have to avoid treating $\rightarrow$ as an intuitive meaning "implication," but rather as its propositional calculus meaning.

Comment: @TimWeah Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you compare a $\forall x \exists y \ \varphi(x,y)$ with the one where the quantifiers are swapped, i.e. $\exists y \forall x \ \varphi(x,y)$ you have:

$\exists y \forall x \ \varphi(x,y) \Rightarrow \forall x \exists y \ \varphi(x,y)$

$\forall x \exists y \ \varphi(x,y) \color{red} \not \Rightarrow \exists y \forall x \ \varphi(x,y)$

However, in this case the two statements are equivalent, since you don't really have any relationship between $x$ and $y$

That is: $\forall x\exists y(P(x)\to Q(y))$ is equivalent to $\exists y\forall x(P(x)\to Q(y))$

To show this, you can use the Prenex Laws:

**Prenex Laws**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$ \forall x \ \varphi \to \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$  \psi \to \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \to \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \to \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \to \psi)$

$  \psi \to \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \to \varphi)$

So:

$\forall x\exists y(P(x)\to Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall x(P(x)\to \exists y \ Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists x \ P(x)\to \exists y \ Q(y) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists y (\exists x \ P(x)\to  \ Q(y)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists y \forall x (P(x)\to  \ Q(y)) $